# Set Selected/ Unselected view color in UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, selection

I have a tableview with which all views will be of clear colour. When user selected a cell I need to make selected tableview cell red and reset all other previous cells to clear colour. 
How can I manage state of the cell whether it is selected or not.

I am using this code to change the color of selected index.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as?  TableViewCell else { return }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

I am not able to reset the previous cell.

Comment: You can use a custom cell to set the selected and unselected UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `override` **`setSelected(_:animated:)`** method in `TableViewCell` and configure the `backgroundColor` based on `selected` state.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.backgroundColor = selected ? .red : .clear
    }
}
```

No need to change the `backgroundColor` in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) method`.

Comment: Actually I need to manage Button action on the cell selection as well. @ PGDev

Comment: @ios button action? Please clarify.

Comment: I am creating a quiz app in which user will select a answer and then click on next button to go to next question .

Comment: It will be added in setselected function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deselectRow` func of tableView :

```
func deselectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, 
    animated: Bool){
    guard let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as?  TableViewCell else { return }
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Based on PGDev's answer you need a property in the view controller to keep the selected index path

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?
```

If no row is selected the property is `nil`

---

In `cellForRow` add a line to manage the selection

```
cell.isSelected = indexPath == selectedIndexPath
```

---

In `didSelectRowAt` compare the just selected index path with `selectedIndexPath`, update `selectedIndexPath` and reload the rows accordingly.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var pathsToReload = [indexPath]
    if let selectedPath = selectedIndexPath {
        if indexPath == selectedPath { // deselect current row
            selectedIndexPath == nil
        } else { // deselect previous row, select current row
            pathsToReload.append(selectedPath)
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    } else { // select current row
        selectedIndexPath == indexPath
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: pathsToReload, with: .automatic)
}
```